# Java - JNDI / Active Directory / Kerberos / WebLogic Server - Password Configuration

Tags: java, active-directory, weblogic, jndi, kerberos

I want to fetch data from an Active Directory using Java and JNDI from my EJB.
Doing this search I need to define a user and a password.
I was thinking of creating a service account (for my server) in the AD.

I will also be using Kerberos protocol and WebLogic Server.
As I understand it now, I need to create a keytab file that will contain this service account's credentials. This keytab file will then be configured in the WebLogic Server?

So, this means that I will have to state the username/password both for the keytab file and in my EJB (*to fetch the data from the AD using JNDI*). What is the best approach for this? Can the keytab file be defined dynamically? Which would simplify changing the password and only doing this at one place.

Answer (score 0):

Have your machine join the domain, start you WebLogic server with the machine account or give access to the machine keytab, create a JDNI resource with the [`DirContextSourceFactory`](http://dirctxsrc.sourceforge.net/dircontextsourcefactory.html) and you are able to access the AD as you wish.