# WebLogic Server - SSL - Multiple certificates

Tags: url, ssl, certificate, weblogic

Is it possible to configure a WebLogic Server (11g) so it uses different certificates for SSL-communication to different URL: s?

In my case I want to use one certificate for internal SSL-server-communication and another one for external communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you're talking about server SSL identity certificate. Since logic servers can have only 1 SSL port and only one alias can be used per logic server, then no you can't do this through server configuration. However you could hard code this behavior into your application, so that when it connects to different urls it will use different identity certificate. You had not specified exactly what you use but maybe this could help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/security/SSL_client.html

Comment: Xargos, as you seem to know about the WebLogic Server, do you also have any advice to give when it comes to my following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173149/java-jndi-active-directory-kerberos-weblogic-server-password-configura